# Generate Ratings

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I am working on a project where a movie review is given and I've to check whether the movie is good or bad by analyzing the review. Using Language processing I've extracted the percentage of supported words(Good) and unsupported words(Bad) in review. Now, I have to get the ratings out of 10 using these percentage. 
Suppose: The product has good and bad percentages. 
Good: 70% Bad: 30% or 
Good: 40% Bad: 50%
and all possible combinations. 
How can I make a general rating out of 10? 
1: Extremely bad 
.
.
5: Average (When Good:50% and Bad: 50%) 
.
.
10: Extremely Good

I've tried some formulas made by myself but those were not good.
i.e (Good/bad) + 4 it can work good if Good is greater or equal to Bad.
Good(50)/Bad(50) + 4 = 5 
Good (70) / bad(30) + 4 = 6 
if Good is lesser than Bad then it always results in 4. Because of bad formula.
Good(30) / bad (60) + 4 = 4.5 
Good(20) / bad (80) + 4 = 4.25

I need a formula or method. Please help.

Comment: What is the _meaning_ of the "good" and "bad" numbers in your input?

Comment: these are just two different variables.

Comment: If the numbers don't have any meaning, then what is wrong with using the function the returns $7$ for all possible inputs? You need to specify some properties that you want the function to have.

Comment: You have examples with Good (90) + Bad (30), so 120% reviews?! Or is it absolute?

Comment: @Pieter21 Sorry it was a mistake. I corrected.

Comment: Does `good` and `bad` always add up to $100\%$? Because you still have some with `good`/`bad` of 40/50 (adds up to 90) and 30/60 (adds up to 90).

Comment: Not always adds up to 100%.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I edited the question. Hope you understand it now. It is actually a project of computer science.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

$$\text{Rating} = 10\cdot \frac{\text{Good}}{\text{Good} + \text{Bad}}?$$

**Examples.**

1. $\text{Good} = 40, \text{Bad} = 60$. Then $\text{Rating = 4}$.
2. $\text{Good} = 20, \text{Bad} = 60$. Then $\text{Rating = 2.5}$.
3. $\text{Good} = 80, \text{Bad} = 20$. Then $\text{Rating = 8}$.

The only problem is that you can get a rating of $0$ if you have $0\%$ in Good.

Comment: Thanks. It is working for dummy values. Now I've to check it on real values.

Comment: *9 + 1 for scale 1..10